# Como inserir a data em documento gerado pelo LaTeX a partir de um argumento da linha de comando?

Tags: latex

Olá.

Estou refatorando um sistema de geração de relatórios com R.

Atualmente os relatórios estão no formato RMarkdown e são gerados automaticamente a partir de arquivos XLSX.

Ocorre que, sendo os relatórios mensais, o campo `date` do front-matter do Rmd é preenchido automaticamente da seguinte forma:

```r
# Código R que busca no XLSX a data base dos dados
ds_file <- "indicadores cm.xlsx"
df <- readxl::read_excel(ds_file, sheet = "Dados")
data_base <- as.Date(df$data_base[1])
periodo <- format(data_base, format = "%B de %Y") # Período dos dados, usados como date
ano_base <- format(data_base, format = "%Y")
```

```yaml
---
title: "Indicadores Fiscais e Gerenciais da Câmara de Vereadores"
author: "Everton da Rosa (Contador CRC RS-076595/O-3)"
date: "`r periodo`"
---
```

Entretando, estou refatorando todo o sistema para que ele gere as tabelas em LaTeX e os gráficos na forma de imagens sem utilizar Rmarkdown, apenas em script R e a ideia é gerar o PDF a partir de um template LaTeX que incorporará as tabelas e gráficos, visto que o texto do relatório é estático.

Contudo, é necessário que o Mês e Ano (hoje como `date` no front-matter do Rmd, e na refatoração o `\date` do LaTeX) também será dinâmico.

Então eu pergunto: Existe alguma forma de o arquivo *.tex ler algo que seja passado via linha de comando (por exemplo `pdflatex report.tex --ano=2022 --mes=Agosto`) e incluir isso em `\date`?

Ou então, detectar o mês e ano para `\date` a partir de algum outro local ou variável (que eu salvaria ao processar os scripts R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fins de registro da solução, após alguns testes aleatórios:

No script `R` que monta as tabelas e os gráficos:

```r
# Carrega os dados
ds_file <- "indicadores cm.xlsx"
df <- readxl::read_excel(ds_file, sheet = "Dados")
# Identifica a data-base
data_base <- as.Date(df$data_base[1])
# Formata para Agosto de 2022 (por exemplo)
periodo <- format(data_base, format = "%B de %Y")
# Escreve para um arquivo *.tex o comando \date{Agosto de 2022}
writeLines(paste("\\date{", periodo, "}", sep = ""), "cache/data.tex")
```

No template LaTeX:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Indicadores Fiscais e Gerenciais da Câmara de Vereadores}
\author{Everton da Rosa - Contador - CRC RS-076595/o-3}
% Importa \date{Agosto de 2022}
\input{"cache/data.tex"}

\begin{document}

...

\end{document}
```